# Is it ok to use 'await' before a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm looping with `Array.prototype.find()` through an array that could get to more then 1000+ elements.

The value I'm getting back is important for the rest of the code to run properly, so I've put an `await`
statement before it to be sure.

Is it ok? is there a better practice?

```
const city = await cities.find(city => city.Text === currentAddress.cityAddress)
```

Comment: It is "ok" but it makes no sense and will not change the behavior.  The `.find()` method is always synchronous and putting `await` before it won't change that.

Comment: Meaning it will always be blocking and if the loop didn't end the rest of the code will not run?

Comment: Yes. `.find()` is synchronous. It will iterate through the array until a match is found or until the end of the array is reached. It cannot be made asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

it is useless and it can even cause you problems, if there is no async stuff in yow loop it will run synchronously

Comment: what kind of problems could it cause?

Comment: The await keyword is only valid inside async functions within regular JavaScript code. If you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a SyntaxError.

await can be used on its own with JavaScript modules.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is an `synchronous` operation. putting the `await` keyword in front of it does not make it more `synchronous`, having said that it should not cause any unexpected issue.

Comment: What kind of unexpected behavior would occur?

Comment: I can't say for sure what could go wrong, but syntactically it's wrong to put the 'awaiter' infront of a sync operation.